# How to merge two .iso split-files into one image-file?

Tags: 12.10, command-line, iso, merge

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/install-android-os-on-pc-with.html), in order to install Android onto my computer via Virtual Box.

My problem is, they want you to download:

- liveandroidv0.3.iso.001
- liveandroidv0.3.iso.002

Then they want you to merge these two files in terminal, with:

```
cat liveandroidv0.3.iso.001 liveandroidv0.3.iso.002 > liveandroidv0.3.iso
```

The problem is, whenever I run the command, I get the following output:

```
cat  liveandroidv0.3.iso.001 liveandroidv0.3.iso.002 > liveandroidv0.3.iso
cat: liveandroidv0.3.iso.001: No such file or directory
cat: liveandroidv0.3.iso.002: No such file or directory
```

So, I was wondering if there was an alternative way to merge these files, or if you guy's could help me merge them this way?

---

**Additional Info**: I downloaded the files to my `/downloads` folder in my `/home` directory.

Comment: Just download the ISO from their site and spare yourself the trouble, 
http://www.android-x86.org/

Comment: As written on the google project page: "v0.3 liveCD released on Aug 21, 2009". This is abandon ware. Go to their official site and download an up to date image, please.

Answer (score 2):

Use the absolute paths of all three files involved. It'll make for one hell of a one liner, but it should do it. E. g.:

```
cat /path/to/liveandroidv0.3.iso.001 /path/to/liveandroidv0.3.iso.002 > /path/to/liveandroidv0.3.iso
```

Answer (score 0):

are you in `Downloads` folder in terminal?

Use `ls`, this should list the files, if not you are not in correct directory in terminal .

Use cd to navigate like `cd Downloads`